# Expo upload background video to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, expo

I'm working on an Expo project where users will take videos and upload them for organization and viewing them. I've been trying to upload videos taken using the expo-camera API to a storage bucket in AWS. I've been using the expo-file-system's upload in background functionality to upload videos, but I've come across an error that I don't have any idea how to handle. It generally happens the bigger the video is, and if it is over a minute, the app is likely to crash when I start to upload. Here is the FileSystem function call I make to upload the video:

```
FileSystem.uploadAsync(awsurl, localVideo, {
        successActionStatus: 201,
        sessionType: FileSystem.FileSystemSessionType.BACKGROUND,
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        fieldName: 'file',
        mimeType: 'video/mov',
        uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,
        parameters: awsparams
      })
```

and here is the error that is occurring

```
Error: Unable to upload the file: 'Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-997 "Lost connection to background transfer service" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/{{bucket}}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/{{bucket}}, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "BackgroundUploadTask <40D1EB30-0F5E-457B-8A19-18610D4A6C3A>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask <40D1EB30-0F5E-457B-8A19-18610D4A6C3A>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=Lost connection to background transfer service}'
```

I've tried multiple combinations of fieldName, mimeType and uploadType, but have had no success in getting large uploads to work. Any ideas how to fix this or effective ways to debug would be great! If anyone knows of a way in Expo to break videos into smaller chunks for uploads that would also be very helpful

Expo version is 43

Comment: is there any update on this one?

Comment: I posted the same issue on GitHub to see where I could get traction. That one has had a response, but not any action that I’m aware of. Here’s a link to it if you want to follow it there: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16453

Comment: thank you for help. i decided to call multipart post request in my native modules, because none of existing libraries is providing what i need.